# Why is my subdomain occasionally not accessible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

I own the following domain name: `joynr.co`

I've configured a subdomain: `promoter.joynr.co`

But sometimes, it's just not working, like a DNS error. Just like if it was still propagating. But it's been a week now :/

Where should I start looking ?

my apache confd files ? .htaccess ? or some configurations at AWS ? It's hosted a AWS, and domain name registered at godaddy.

[I've followed this threat to configurer AWS/Go Daddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009512/how-to-create-domain-subdomain-in-aws)

Also, I've configured the confd so when accessing promoter.joynr.co you browse a different folder/website than when going to joynr.co (in /var/www ).

.htaccess is empty

Many Thanks

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: The DNS entry promoter.joynr.co doesn't seem to exist. Check in Route 53 if you've defined it, post details if so.

Comment: Thanks Josip, I've edited my question, here is all I have in Route 53 for promoter.joynr.co . Note that I also have a host on for joynr.co . Is there any security issues I should be aware of posting this to public on SO ? Many Thanks

Comment: It seems to be working now...? As for security issues, is this supposed to be a public website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have `promoter` NS records within the `joynr.co` domain, in order for the eponymous subdomain to be able to be recursively resolved.

Apparently in Route 53 you just do it the old-fashioned way - take the NS records you see in the `promoter.joynr.co` domain and copy&paste them into the parent domain, cf. http://github.com/toddm92/aws/wiki/Route-53-Subdomains

(Moved from comments and condensed.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've seen much more detailed documentations than the one you shared with in the end less information. Thanks for sharing. I think it did the trick ! Simple and straight forward :)